# C code to print the unique numbers of an array

Tags: c

I want to create a C program that merges 4 unsorted arrays, sort them and print all the unique numbers from the new merged array.
The results are not correct, but i don't know why.
Here is an example:

1. a[1,5,13,3]
2. b[3,5,9,1,23]
3. c[5,23,3,18]
4. d[1]
5. a_b[1,5,13,3,3,5,9,1,23]
6. c_d[5,23,3,18,1]
7. e[1,1,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,9,13,18,23,23]

### Prints only the unique numbers from array e: *13,18,9*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_uniques(int x[], int sizex)
{
int i, j;
if(sizex == 0)
    return;
if(sizex == 1){
    printf("%d\n", x[0]);
    return;
}
i = j = 0;
while(i != sizex){
    i++;
    if(i != sizex && x[i] == x[j])
        continue;
    if((i - j) == 1)
        printf("%d\n", x[j]);
    j = i;
}
}

/* print unique numbers from sorted array */

/* merge two already sorted arrays */
void merge(int m[], int x[], int sizex, int y[], int sizey)
{
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
while (i < sizex && j < sizey)
{
    if (x[i] <= y[j])
        m[k++] = x[i++];
    else
        m[k++] = y[j++];
}
while (i < sizex)
    m[k++] = x[i++];
while (j < sizey)
    m[k++] = y[j++];
}

/* compare function for qsort() */
int cmp(const int *i, const int *j)
{
return *i - *j;
} 

int main()
{
int i, j,a[30],b[30],c[30],d[30],sizea,sizeb,sizec,sized;
printf("Enter the size of array A: ");
scanf("%d",&sizea);
printf("Enter the %d elements of array A:\n", sizea);
for(i=0;i<sizea;i++)
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
printf("Enter the size of array B: ");
scanf("%d",&sizeb);
printf("Enter the %d elements of array B:\n", sizeb);
for(i=0;i<sizeb;i++)
scanf("%d",&b[i]);
printf("Enter the size of array C: ");
scanf("%d",&sizec);
printf("Eisagete ta %d stoixeia tou pinaka C:\n", sizec);
for(i=0;i<sizec;i++)
scanf("%d",&c[i]);
printf("Eisagete to mege8os tou pinaka D: ");
scanf("%d",&sized);
printf("Eisagete ta %d stoixeia tou pinaka D:\n", sized);
for(i=0;i<sized;i++)
scanf("%d",&d[i]);
int a_b[32];
int c_d[32];
int e[64];
int sizea_b, sizec_d, sizee;

sizea = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
sizeb = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
sizec = sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);
sized = sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]);
sizea_b = sizea   + sizeb;
sizec_d = sizec   + sized;
sizee   = sizea_b + sizec_d;

/* sort the arrays */
qsort(a, sizea, sizeof(a[0]), cmp);
qsort(b, sizeb, sizeof(b[0]), cmp);
qsort(c, sizec, sizeof(c[0]), cmp);
qsort(d, sized, sizeof(d[0]), cmp);

/* merge the arrays */
merge(a_b, a, sizea, b, sizeb);
merge(c_d, c, sizec, d, sized);
merge(e, a_b, sizea_b, c_d, sizec_d);

print_uniques(e, sizee);

return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Again with the crazy byte-counting.  Are you running on some RAM-restricted embedded system?

Comment: @ch3rub7 Changed the lengths to 30 but again there are some issues.

Comment: hmm... it's better if you include errors in your question.. like desired output and the actual output you are getting

Comment: @ch3rub7 After testing the code, the main problem is when i want to merge a_b[] and c_d[] to e[].

Comment: you want to print `unique element = 6, at index = 16` right? @Aldi

Comment: @ch3rub7 I want to print 5 and 6. The method works only if there is only 1 unique number.

Comment: @Aldi - the title should be changed to merge 4 already sorted arrays, then print unique numbers from the merged array.

Comment: @rcgldr It was just coincidence that the numbers were sorted.

Comment: @Aldi - "merge 4 arrays" implies that the arrays are already sorted. So the problem could be "concatenate 4 unsorted arrays, and sort the concatenated array", or "sort 4 unsorted arrays, then merge them to form a sorted array" .

Comment: 1 function. 19 repetitive structures. Maintenance limbo. Debugging hell. Only One could save them all. The One. His name is Stack Overflow.

Comment: @bolov Added comments. Now it's easier to understand how simple is the program. I am a newbie btw.

Comment: @Aldi good job. When you learn about functions you should start immediately to take advantage of them: as many and as small as possible, each doing one thing and doing it well. For now, it's good enough. I wasn't necessary criticizing you, but unfortunately, that's how code by beginners looks. And hard as hell to debug, which adds to the difficulty of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed example code to get user input. The merge part is the same as Antoine Mathys answer, so this code example mostly shows a simple way to print unique numbers from a sorted array. Added qsort() calls to sort the 4 arrays, since it's not clear if the arrays were supposed to be already sorted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* print unique numbers from sorted array */
void print_uniques(int x[], int sizex)
{
int i, j;
    if(sizex == 0)
        return;
    i = j = 0;
    while(i != sizex){
        i++;
        if(i != sizex && x[i] == x[j])
            continue;
        if((i - j) == 1)
            printf("%d\n", x[j]);
        j = i;
    }
}

/* merge two already sorted arrays */
void merge(int m[], int x[], int sizex, int y[], int sizey)
{
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    while (i < sizex && j < sizey) 
    {
        if (x[i] <= y[j]) 
            m[k++] = x[i++];
        else 
            m[k++] = y[j++];
    }
    while (i < sizex) 
        m[k++] = x[i++];
    while (j < sizey) 
        m[k++] = y[j++];
}

/* compare function for qsort() */
int cmp(const int *i, const int *j)
{
    return *i - *j;
}

/* get data (no size check) */
int getdata(int x[], char l)
{
int s, i;
    printf("Enter the number of elements for %c : ", l);
    if(0 == scanf("%d", &s))
        return 0;
    for(i = 0; i < s; i++){
        printf("Enter an element for %c : ", l);
        scanf("%d", x+i);
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
int a[64], b[64], c[64], d[64];
int a_b[128], c_d[128];
int e[256];
int sizea, sizeb, sizec, sized;
int sizea_b, sizec_d, sizee;

    sizea = getdata(a, 'A');
    sizeb = getdata(b, 'B');
    sizec = getdata(c, 'C');
    sized = getdata(d, 'D');

    sizea_b = sizea   + sizeb;
    sizec_d = sizec   + sized;
    sizee   = sizea_b + sizec_d;

    /* sort the arrays */
    qsort(a, sizea, sizeof(a[0]), cmp);
    qsort(b, sizeb, sizeof(b[0]), cmp);
    qsort(c, sizec, sizeof(c[0]), cmp);
    qsort(d, sized, sizeof(d[0]), cmp);

    /* merge the arrays */
    merge(a_b, a, sizea, b, sizeb);
    merge(c_d, c, sizec, d, sized);
    merge(e, a_b, sizea_b, c_d, sizec_d);

    printf("\n");
    print_uniques(e, sizee);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternate get data that lets user input multiple elements on a single line without having to specify the number of elements.

```
/* get data (no size check) */
int getdata(int x[], char l)
{
char d[] = " ,\t\n";
char t[80];
int i = 0;
char *pt;
    printf("enter element(s) for %c :\n", l);
    if(NULL == fgets(t, sizeof(t), stdin))
        return 0;
    pt = strtok(t, d);
    while(pt){
        sscanf(pt, "%d", x+i);
        i++;
        pt = strtok(NULL, d);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Based on OP's comment. looks like the title is wrong. The 4 arrays may not sorted. They could each be sorted, and then merged, or concatenated and then sorted. It's not clear which is to be done.

Comment: @rcgldr Okay, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @AntoineMathys - I misunderstood the print uniques part, fixed it now, using a single loop, taking advantage of the fact that the array is sorted.

Comment: @rcgldr I just updated my code.

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you for your help. I will test it.

Comment: @rcgldr Unfortunately the code, doesn't work. It returns 2 errors and exits. (fatal error: no input files and Invalid argument)

Comment: @Aldi - strange, I've run it with a redirected input file and with manual input. I'm running on WIndows, using Visual Studio, what are you using?

Comment: @rcgldr I am using Code::Blocks. (i am a CS student btw)

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you! I had an issue with the compiler! Your code is great!

Comment: @Aldi - good to see it's working now. I deleted my prior comments to clean things up a bit.

Comment: @rcgldr Is there any other way without using stable values on the arrays at first (a[64])? Because we don't know if the user may enter more than 64 values or not.

Comment: @Aldi - If the user inputs one line of data on the console, and only 80 characters, that's 40 single digit values at most.  To handle variable size, change the arrays to be pointers to integers, and malloc room for 64 integers (malloc(64*sizeof(int)). If while reading data, you get to 64 integers, then realloc to 128 integers, then if needed, realloc to 256 integers, and so on, doubling the number of integers with each realloc. Once a, b, c, d are read, then use malloc for a_b, c_d, and e, based on the sizes of a, b, c, d. Don't forget to free them just before program exit.

Comment: @rcgldr All right, thank you for your clear answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you merge `a_b` with `c_d` you have the sizes back to front with

```
while(i<size3+size4 && j<size1+size2)
```

This should be

```
while(i<size1+size2 && j<size3+size4)
```

The same applies below when you merge the remaining parts of the arrays, and these have an additional problem: instead of repeating the `while` loops you used to build `a_b` and `c_d` you've used a different technique. I suggest revisiting this section building `e`, and making it work like you did when buildling `a_b` and `c_d`.

Here is the corrected code - except I didn't look at the part after the creation of `e[]` as I am not sure what you are trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int size1 = 4, a[] = {1,1,1,2};
    int size2 = 4, b[] = {2,2,2,3};
    int size3 = 4, c[] = {3,3,3,4};
    int size4 = 5, d[] = {4,4,4,5,6};
    int a_b[30], c_d[30], e[30];
    int i,j,k,t, sizefull;

    sizefull=size1+size2+size3+size4;
    printf("%d\n", sizefull);

    i=j=k=0;
    while (i < size1 && j < size2) 
    {
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) 
            {
            a_b[k] = a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
            }
       else {
            a_b[k] = b[j];
            k++;
            j++;
            }
    }
    while (i < size1) 
    {
        a_b[k] = a[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < size2) 
    {
        a_b[k] = b[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    printf("\nMerged array is :");
    for (i = 0; i < size1 + size2; i++)
        printf("%d ", a_b[i]);

    i=j=k=0;
    while (i < size3 && j < size4) {
        if (c[i] <= d[j]) {
            c_d[k] = c[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            c_d[k] = d[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i < size3) {
        c_d[k] = c[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < size4) {
        c_d[k] = d[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    printf("\nMerged array is :");
    for (i = 0; i < size3 + size4; i++)
        printf("%d ", c_d[i]);

    i=j=k=0;
    while (i < size1+size2 && j < size3+size4) 
    {
        if (a_b[i] <= c_d[j]) 
            {
            e[k] = a_b[i];
            i++;
            k++;
            }
       else {
            e[k] = c_d[j];
            k++;
            j++;
            }
    }
    while (i < size1+size2) 
    {
        e[k] = a_b[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < size3+size4) 
    {
        e[k] = c_d[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }

    printf("\n After merging: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < sizefull; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", e[i]);
    }

    for (i=0;i<sizefull;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<sizefull;j++)
        {
            if(e[i]>e[j])
            {
                t=e[i];
                e[i]=e[j];
                e[j]=t;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nAscending Order is:");
    for(j=0;j<sizefull;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",e[j]);
    }

    printf("\n\n Final Array is \n");
    for(i=0;i<sizefull;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d",e[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<sizefull;)
    {
        for(j = (i + 1); j<sizefull; j++)
        {
            if( e[i] != e[j])
                break;
        }
        printf("\nunique element = %d, at index = %d\n", e[i], i);
        printf("\nunique element = %d, at index = %d\n", e[i], i);
        i = j;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
17

Merged array is :1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3
Merged array is :3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 6
 After merging:
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 6
Ascending Order is:1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 6

 Final Array is
 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 6
unique element = 1, at index = 0

unique element = 1, at index = 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I keep getting numbers like 58359348. :(

Comment: That's because you didn't chage it properly.

Comment: @Aldi I have added code to the answer.

Comment: Did you test your code and it worked? Because i still see wrong numbers at the output.

Comment: @Aldi yes I tested the code. I also tested some half-changed code following your earlier remark, and saw the wrong numbers. I'll post my program output in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Well First, You should try to put some comments on your code so that it becomes easy for others to read your code at one go. And I can see a lot of errors in your code. You have taken incorrect sizes of arrays ans also a for loop of yours is incorrect. The loop after you printed your final array  `for(i=0; i<sizefull;)` is not correct.
I will try to provide a simple solution to your problem.
First, merge the four arrays, Second, perform a sorting algorithm(bubble, say), then try to find unique numbers from them.

```
int main()
{
    int size1, size2, size3, size4,sizefull,a[30],b[30],c[30],d[30],e[120];      
    int i,j,t,match,temp;
    printf("Insert the size of A: ");
        scanf("%d",&size1);
    printf("Insert %d elements of A:\n", size1);
    for(i=0;i<size1;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("Insert the size of B: ");
        scanf("%d",&size2);
    printf("Insert %d elements of B:\n", size2);
    for(i=0;i<size2;i++)
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    printf("Insert the size of C: ");
        scanf("%d",&size3);
    printf("Insert %d elements of C:\n", size3);
    for(i=0;i<size3;i++)
        scanf("%d",&c[i]);
    printf("Insert the size of D: ");
        scanf("%d",&size4);
    printf("Insert %d elements of D:\n", size4);
    for(i=0;i<size4;i++)
        scanf("%d",&d[i]);
    sizefull=size1+size2+size3+size4;
    //The below code is for copying.
    i=0;
    j=0;
    while(i<size1)  
    {
             e[j]=a[i];
             i++;
             j++;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<size2)  
    {
             e[j]=b[i];
             i++;
             j++;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<size3)  
    {
             e[j]=c[i];
             i++;
             j++;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<size4)  
    {
             e[j]=d[i];
             i++;
             j++;
    }
     //bubble sort
    for(i=0;i<sizfull-i;i++)
    {
         for(j=0;j<sizefull-i;j++)
         {
              if(e[j]>e[j+1])
              {
                  temp=e[j];
                  e[j]=e[j+1];
                  e[j+1]=temp;
              }
         }
    }
    //Code below is for finding and printing unique numbers.
    for(i=0;i<sizefull-1;i++)
    {
        match=0; 
        for(j=i+1;j<sizefull;j++)
         {
             if(e[i]==e[j])
             {
                 match++;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if(match==0)
         printf("unique number=%d at index %d",e[i],i);
    }


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your method doesn't work. :(